# Character pointer and strings

Tags: c, string, char, char-pointer

Experts there is a question given in the book "Let us C" where the author has asked to write the output of the given program.
The program is-

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char s[]="Churchgate: no church no gate";
    char t[40];
    char *ss,*tt;
    ss=s;
    while(*ss!='\0')
        *tt++=*ss++;
    printf("%s\n",t);
    return 0;
}
```

When I tried it on  my gcc compiler, the output was core-dumped. Please explain why.Here ss and tt are character pointers. 
Here I also don't understand that what's the meaning of the statement ss=s;
I mean we can't directly copy a string unless we are copying it character by character. And ss is a character pointer so it points to a character then ss=s means what? Does it mean it will point to the byte whose address is the ASCII value of s?
I also don't understand this statement *tt++=*ss++. I don't have any clue about it. Please elaborate its meaning.

Next I don't understand why printf("%s\n",t) is used as though t is of character type but it is not storing anything according to the program.

Comment: `tt` is pointing nowhere....

Comment: Maybe you wanted `tt=t`; and then at the end `*tt='\0'`

Comment: Also, indentation:(

Comment: The "warning" section here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list says the following about the book you are reading: `It is a horribly outdated book that teaches Turbo C and has lot of obsolete, misleading and downright incorrect material.`

Comment: Note: ASCII would not be used. The literal string is encoded with the [execution character set](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html#Character-sets) by the compiler. [`-fexec-charset`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Invocation.html#Invocation).

Answer (score 0):

First thing first'
Array name is nothing but the pointer that holds the address of the first element.
So,

```
char s[]="Churchgate: no church no gate";
```

here s is the pointer name. And it holds the address of 'C' of the string.
Now you have declared another pointer which is also a character type i.e. ss.

so, ss=s; means ss is also holding the address which is held by s also.

As you haven't store anything to t so it will print garbage. Similarly pointer tt is not storing any address initially(Garbage).
**And lastly and most importantly**
you can't perform this op:
*tt++=*ss++;
**probably show you error of lvalue recquired.**